# How would I properly filter dates that are in between a start date and end date, using the Java Streams API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream, jhipster, localdate

So I've been using the Java Streams API, and I'm trying to filter dates in my DB, in which the start date of something is before the current date, and the end date is after the current date. I've tried multiple things, but nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

Here's what I've tried so far:

> I've tried implementing the `ChronoLocalDate` interface, and used `.isBefore() and` .isAfter()`, but the dates did not filter properly
>
> At this point I've now tried sticking with `LocalDate`, and I've tried converting `LocalDate.now()` to the `yyyy-MM-dd` format (which is the date format in my DB) using the following code:

```
LocalDate rightNow = LocalDate.now();
String formatString = rightNow.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

However, this doesn't work and results in the following error:

```
The method format(DateTimeFormatter) is undefined for the type LocalDate
```

I got the above code from various 2018 examples. Is `LocalDate.format()` already depreciated?

Also, I haven't been able to find any relevant examples for filtering between a start date and end date using LocalDate.

Any help from here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to get date from db ?

Comment: I was already getting all of the dates from the DB before. It's just that it would show all of the dates instead of filtering them, because of ChronoLocalDate being the wrong use for it if I'm not wrong. So I switched over to using Localdate, but I have no idea what I would use in a query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what was wrong. I was importing the wrong `LocalDate` from `java.joda` instead of `java.time`.

So from here, I'm not using `ChronoLocalDate` anymore, but the `LocalDate` from `java.time`, and my filtering now works perfectly. Very silly mistake on my part, but I figured it out.

Thank you everyone who also tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like following using `Java8 streams` and `LocalDate`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String startTextDateFromDB = "2019-03-14";
        String endTextDateFromDB = "2019-05-14";
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(startTextDateFromDB, dateFormatter);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(endTextDateFromDB, dateFormatter);
        List<LocalDate> getList = getDatesInBetween(startDate, endDate);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(getList));

    }

    //return a list of all localdates between two dates
    public static List<LocalDate> getDatesInBetween(
            LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        //get numbers between two dates
        long numbersBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
        //collect each localdate from start date until end date 
        return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
                .limit(numbersBetween)
                .mapToObj(i -> startDate.plusDays(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below an example of how to apply a filter. I assume you have a list with `Foo` elements, and this class has two fields: `startDate` and `endDate`.

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
List<LocalDate> dates = dbEntries.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.getStartDate().compareTo(now) < 0 && t.getEndDate().compareTo(now) > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Spring Boot is probably able to automatically convert dates within the database to appropriate Temporal instances. Perhaps with the use of annotations.

Answer (score 0):

## Filter in SQL

> So I've been using the Java Streams API, and I'm trying to filter dates in my DB,

That's a contradiction. If you are filtering dates within the database as part of your query (generally the best approach), then you have no need for Java streams.

### Half-Open query in SQL

Write your query. I assume we are querying a pair of columns of a data type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE` type, for a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

In this query code we use the Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is generally the best approach to handling spans-of-time.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE start_ <= ? AND stop_ > ? ;" ;
```

### Today

We need today's date to pass into that `?` placeholder.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

### Pass value for placeholder

We have today's date, so pass it to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , today ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , today ) ;
```

## Filter in Java

Generally is best to perform as much filtering as possible within your SQL, to execute on the server-side in the database. Powerful enterprise-quality database engines such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) are highly optimized for just such work.

But, perhaps you have some reason to do this in Java rather than the database.

You have to retrieve row by row in Java, [pulling from a result set in JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html). So you might as well filter then. Which means there is no need for Java streams. Just compare the values of `LocalDate` for your start and stop values.

> I've tried implementing the ChronoLocalDate interface, and used .isBefore() and.isAfter()`, but the dates did not filter properly

You seem to be confused about how *java.time* works in this regard. **The [`ChronoLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html) interface is not for *you* to implement.** The interface is already implemented in the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) calendar system commonly used throughout the West of much of the rest of the world. That interface exists for authors implementing various calendaring systems, not for you and I. There are about a dozen, at least, such calendaring systems already implemented for Java, including some bundled with Java such as Islamic, Japanese, and Thai calendars.

By the way, the *java.time* JavaDoc explains that you should generally avoid using the more general interfaces. They exist mainly for the benefit of those implementing calendaring systems, as described above. In day-to-day business programming, you should usually be using the more concrete classes. For example, `LocalDate` rather than `ChronoLocalDate`.

To compare `LocalDate` objects, call [`LocalDate::isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isBefore(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#isEqual(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate)), `equals`, or `compareTo` methods

```
List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>() ;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    …
    LocalDate start = rs.getObject( "start_" , LocalDate.class ) ;
    LocalDate stop = rs.getObject( "stop_" , LocalDate.class ) ;
    if( ( ! start.isAfter( today ) ) && ( stop.isBefore( today ) ) { 
        Event event = … ;
        events.add( event ) ;
    } else { 
        // Skip this row. Does not meet our criterion of containing today's date.
    }
}
```

### `LocalDateRange`

Such work is made easier with the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. This project adds functionality to the *java.time* classes.

For your particular situation, you may find the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class helpful. This class represents a span-of-time as a pair of `LocalDate` objects. Helpful comparison methods include `abuts`, `contains`, `overlaps`, and so on. These work by default according to the Half-Open approach, although you can specify fully-closed (beginning and ending both *inclusive*) optionally.

Let's use this class to modify the comparison in our sample code above.

```
List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>() ;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    …
    LocalDate start = rs.getObject( "start_" , LocalDate.class ) ;
    LocalDate stop = rs.getObject( "stop_" , LocalDate.class ) ;
    LocalDateRange dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;   // Instantiate the date range.
    if( ( dateRange.contains( today ) ) {                            // Call `LocalDateRange::contains` rather than write our own comparison logic.
        Event event = … ;
        events.add( event ) ;
    } else { 
        // Skip this row. Does not meet our criterion of containing today's date.
    }
}
```

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> `LocalDate rightNow = LocalDate.now();`
>   `String formatString = rightNow.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);`

Why are you generating strings? I see no need for strings given your problem statement. When working with date-time values, use date-time objects. Do not use strings for date-time business logic.

## Tutorial

Tip: Read through [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) on *java.time* provided free-of-cost by Oracle.